# Fullcalendar <- Radicale

Tags: fullcalendar, radicale

I want to use fullcalendar to display a calendar for my family, which works fine when using local ICS files as an event source.

How can I use a remote Caldav source - in my case radicale? Radicale itself works fine and serves an ICS file when I use a Radicale URL.

Using the same URL with fullcalendar brings up nothing. What can I do?

Thanks for any support!
Regards,

Christian

- used fullcalendar successfully with local event source (*.ics)
- established a radicale Caldav server working fine for iOS and Android Clients
- tried using same URL for fullcalendar, no events are displayed

Comment: When you try to link the remote ICS to fullCalendar, how did you do it? Please show the fullCalendar code and a sample URL of the ICS file (doesn't need to be the real one if you don't want to share it, just something in the same format). Also, what debugging have you done? Have you looked in your browser's Network tool and Console to see if any errors or problems occur when fullCalendar tries to download and parse the ics file? For example, maybe the request to download it failed, or the data format is wrong, or there's some kind of JS error in the console?

Comment: ...I was able to solve the problem with your hints - checking the console I found an error regarding CORS.
Adding a header to my radicale config ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") fixed the problem - sorry, I'm all new to this.
Thank you!
Christian

Answer (score 1):

Checking the console while following the hints of ADyson I found an error regarding CORS. Adding a header to my radicale config ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") fixed the problem.